# Why TODO in controllers sometimes can't be compiled, in play2?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

`TODO` is convenient when coding controllers:

```
object Application extends Controller {

   def test = Action { TODO }

}
```

It's fine. But this:

```
def login = Action { implicit request => TODO }
```

It won't pass the compilation, the error message is:

```
type mismatch; found : play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] 
required: play.api.mvc.Result
```

I have to remove the `iplicit request` part, or use `Ok("todo")` instead, which is not convenient.

How to fix it or do I miss something?

Comment: Just hit this myself -- if you have a complex controller method that you wish to get back to later but don't want to break everything up just to appease the compiler it's a bit of a pain. Thanks for the Ok("Todo") work-around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **Guillaume Bort** said in [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/YyKxp17BZCE), it's actually an Action, not a result. So we should use it as:

```
def test = TODO
```